# Eclipse plugins for developing RESTful Web Services

Tags: eclipse, rest, plugins, service, web

I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin that makes writing RESTful Web Services with JAX-RX easier and faster, preferably a plugin that can generate code from a given database. NetBeans can automatically create RESTful web services from a database, entity classes or patterns and I'm looking for something similar in Eclipse.

So far I'm only aware of a wizard that comes with Glassfish that can create a web service from a pattern.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.